# Существуют ли библиотеки для питона, с нецензурной лексикой на русском языке? или как создать хорошую стабильную проверку?

Tags: python, telebot, поиск-библиотек, проверка-орфографии

Написал бота на питоне, также создал проверку на нецензурную лексику по списку, к сожалению люди простым образом обходят эту проверку, заменяя символы. В интернете увидел библиотеку с проверкой на нецензурность, но она поддерживает только английский... Может быть есть такая же на русском? или как создать хорошую стабильную проверку?

Comment: Подстрахуй, оскорблять, колебаться

Comment: @andreymal, поэтому и нужен словарь с различными словоформами или какой-то код знающий морфологию. Простым поиском подстрок не обойтись

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/145868/ полезная статья